# how to get onKeyPressed Duration?

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to create a snake game where i use arrow keys or WASD to move the snake.
Initially the snake is slow and moves at 2 fps speed (like the classic snake game), i want the snake to move faster when i am holding down one of the keys and set it to original speed when i release it.

i tried changing the movement rate inside onKeyPressed like so:

```
scene.setOnKeyPressed(event -> {input = event.getCode().toString();
            for (String acceptedKey : acceptedKeys) {
                if (event.getCode().toString().contains(acceptedKey)) {
                    movement.setRate(4);
                    break;
                }
            }
        });
```

Then changing it to normal rate when i released it:

```
scene.setOnKeyReleased(event -> movement.setRate(1));
```

*movement is a Timeline which starts since the beginning of game till stopped or death of snake.

The code works as i intended But every time i hit a key it speeds up for a cycle and then slows down.
I want the speed to change only when i hold a key for a certain duration (say 400 milliseconds) so is there a way i can put an if statement that checks duration of onKeypressed()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of handling this complicated logic in the listener, set a boolean flag that is flipped on when a key is pressed.

```java
scene.setOnKeyPressed(event -> {input = event.getCode().toString();
            for (String acceptedKey : acceptedKeys) {
                if (event.getCode().toString().contains(acceptedKey)) {
                    acceptedKeyBeingPressed = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        });
scene.setOnKeyReleased(event -> acceptedKeyBeingPressed = false);
```

---

Then keep track of time with some sort of `numTicksHeld` variable when the flag `acceptedKeyPressed` is `true`.

Check if `acceptedKeyPressed` is true on each tick. Reset the `numTicksHeld` variable to 0 when `acceptedKeyPressed` is `false`. If it is `true`, increment by one. If `numTicksHeld` is above some threshold, `movement.setRate(4)`.

I don't know what the tick/update method looks like in your framework but it would be something like:

```java
public void tick() {
    if(acceptedKeyPressed) {
        numTicksHeld++;
        if(numTicksHeld > KEY_HELD_THRESHOLD)
            movement.setRate(4)
    } else {
        numTicksHeld = 0;
        movement.setRate(1)
    }
}
```